# Issue with PHP $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] and openvpn

Tags: centos, php, openvpn

I have an openvpn server with public and static address 77.77.77.77, and a local client called 'julieta' running Centos with PHP and, 'julieta', has a full DMZ from the openvpn server; so when I put the main ip 77.77.77.77 everything goes to julieta no matter which port is. Works like a charm except from one thing.

When I use in julieta the PHP function $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] (this function gives the IP address from which the request was sent to the web server, in this case julieta), the function only returns the internal host of vpn server (in this case 172.27.224.1), not the real visitor ip.

So, looks like all my visitors come from te same address.

what im missing?

I really aprecciate any help.
Javier

Comment: I don't think the words you have used mean quite what they think. DMZ's are not normally associated with VPNs (although I grant its possible). Can you describe your network connectivity - ie where does the VPN terminate, where does it originate, what is its purpose and does it push/pull a default route? Is 77.77.77.77 a VPN IP ? Are you testing from internally, across the VPN, externally?

Comment: Thanks David, I have something like this:

77.77.77.77 is an example ip.

The main server is a VPS (77.77.77.77) in a remote DC running openvpn, openvpn internal gateway is 172.27.224.1; on the VPS a made a full DMZ to the user julieta, julieta is a local server running on  mi LAN and is connected to the VPS. So when I put 77.77.77.77 goes to my local server. 

Tunnel works perfect, I have to do this because I need more space and the VPS are very expensive to me.

Comment: Still don't fully understand your setup (but I am starting to suspect the problem is the way NAT is set up and/or your routing is different to what you think). Some observations that may help. $SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]  is the IP address the photo server sees, so its a routing/nat, not php or web server related. Machines have interfaces (not so much users in context of routing) and OpenVPN presents with a client and server IP. If Julietta has the VPN endpoint 172.27.224.1 then that IP address represents Juliet's on the other side of the VPN.

Comment: Can you clarify if Julietta is a web client or web server, and likewise if she us a VPN client or server.  Are using the VPS to give you a static IP address which you then forward to Julietta to answer for? If so, can you advise your nat/firewall rules, why you have a DMZ at all and what your iptables/firewall/nat/forwarding rules are?

Comment: Thanks again, and you're right, Julieta  is a web server running my php script.  She uses a VPN client and use the VPS to get a static IP. its my first time using openvpn, so, I  activate the DMZ on the VPS with the GUI. Just put the main IP and all the traffic goes to Julieta. The script works fine and I can see the server (Julieta) over the internet. But the scripts always returns the internal address.

Comment: It sounds very much like their is an issue with the address translation on your router - specifically it appears you are NATTING on all Interfaces.  Can you update your post with how you set up the VPN - especially how you set up the DMZ, NAT/Masquerading etc.  The output of "iptables -t NAT -vnL" on the VPN box might also prove useful.